# Wrong whitebalace/colorgrade for arw files in ImageMagick - updated -

Tags: vb.net, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I want to convert SONY raw files (.ARW) to jpg with imagemagick.
But there is a problem with the whitebalance (probably).

When I open the files in ACDSee or XNView, they look like the jpg-version off the camera, but when I open them in imagemagick Display, they are much darker and more reddish.

**Obviously there are informations about color in the RAW file, but imagemagick cannot interprete them.** Is there any way to extract those informations and apply them separately?

I am in the process of writing a tool to automatically download and publish fotos from the camera, therefore I tried imagemagick.NET (AnyCPU, v11.1) - the conversion program works fine, but the color-problem is the same.

**Converted with imagemagick:**
[image: converted with imagemagick]

**Converted with XnView (or any other graphics utility)**
[image: converted with XnView (same as other Graphics utilities)]

For anyone coming across this: according to Fred Weinhaus' comment I added this to my VB

```
    Dim settings As New MagickReadSettings
    settings.Format = MagickFormat.Arw
    settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.Arw, "use-camera-wb", "true")

    Using Image As New MagickImage(input, settings)
```

Comment: What was your imagemagick command line?  See -defines at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported for ARW where it says: "Set -define dng:use-camera-wb=true to use the RAW-embedded color profile for Sony cameras. You can also set these options: use-auto-wb, use-auto-bright, and output-color."

Comment: Thats already much better. It is still too dark, but the wb is ok now - I will experiment further and update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Post your ARW image and output examples and code to the ImageMagick GIT forum. I suspect there is more information in the file header than ImageMagick is currently using or can use. Did you try the other -define options?  Have you tried the equivalent of -auto-level?